# What is the relevance of "so far so good" in the last scene of La Haine?

Tags: dialogue, la-haine

Would you kindly share the deep meaning of this great quote from the perspective of where it appears in the final scene of La Haine?

> Vinz: It's about a society on its way down. And as it falls, it keeps telling itself: "So far so good... So far so good... So far so good." It's not how you fall that matters. It's how you land.

I understand the straight forward meaning of the expression... but I wanted to know the reason why it fits in that last scene.

Comment: where does the quote comes from?

Comment: Its from La Haine... I couldn't found any tag for this great movie. @Federico

Comment: It's based on an old joke. What about it don't you understand?

Comment: I think this question should be posted on https://english.stackexchange.com/ or https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-expression-so-far-so-good

Comment: its a question regarding a quote from a movie... i understand the straight forward meaning... but i wanted to know the reason why it fits on that last scene... i wanted to know the meaning from that movie perspective... I'm sorry if its not a appropriate question for this site.. @Moritz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This quote depicts the view society has regarding the situation of people in the blocks, like the characters of the movie.

The society let things get worse and worse because "so far it's good" without taking in consideration that, at one point, the whole situation will catastrophicly blows up, hence the "It's how you land".

It the whole idea of the film, the "rupture point". I don't know how much details you expect to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

The "So far so good" comes from a joke in french (and maybe in other language I guess):

"An optimistic man jump from a building, and what does he says at every floor ?
- So far, so good"

So in the end, he will obviously die, but while he's falling, he keep saying to himself that's eveything's ok.

Comment: The entire point of the joke is that the jumper is an optimist, not a pessimist.

Comment: @Tetsujin a naive optimist.

Answer (score 0):

The quote is about what I call the elastic band effect that is inherent to some natural phenomena.

Pull on the elastic band a bit and it adapts.

Pull on it too much and it snaps.

So in the movie it does have to do with the breaking point as @[DiOldDisplay](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/18783/diolddisplay) says.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works as a commentary of the characters in the film but it’s quoting/ sampling The Magnificent Seven (1960) in which one of the seven tells the same story.